# real multiply effect with svg?

Tags: html, css, svg, filter

I was wondering if there was a way to apply a real multiply effect on a svg element ? I tried various solution found here but it seems like the multiply effect in svg is applyied on the object itself not on the elements behind like photoshop does. Is there a way to do it in svg or with any other method ?

Here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/pool4/H7GLE/

```
    <div id="bg">
    <svg id="logo" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 55.7" xml:space="preserve">
        <filter id="multiply">
            <feBlend mode="multiply"/>
        </filter>
        <g>...
    </svg>
    </div>

#logo:hover {
        filter:url(#multiply);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "multiply"?

Comment: @Paulie_D Sure, I mean getting the shade of the element and applying them to the elements behind. My example with multiply applied on the #logo http://imageshack.com/a/img691/4503/5cwm.jpg as you can see, you can see the wall relief through it since only the shade applied on the wall.

Comment: Nope. CSS can't handle that AFAIK. JS might be able to though...

Comment: Google for feBlend tutorial and get this on the first page which shows you proper syntax: http://www.svgbasics.com/filters1.html

Comment: @Michael Mullany The problem is that this syntax assume that you want to mix 2 "images" not a svg vector and a image, Not even mentionning a background image... I had a look at that answer earlier as well but it didn't help as <g> doesn't seem to work inside a filter tag and that any "result" outside of the filter tag isn't read. i.e : http://jsfiddle.net/pool4/4QZ54/ http://jsfiddle.net/pool4/Lcux6/

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a part of the SVG spec that would [allow filters to grab the "background" behind the element being filtered](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#AccessingBackgroundImage), and use that as the second input image to the filter.  But none of the browsers even implement this for SVG content, let alone for SVG filters applied directly to HTML content.  As @ErikDahlstrom points out, Adobe has been pushing for blend modes in HTML, so that might happen sooner than background images in SVG filters.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to multiply an SVG shape with a CSS-defined background (except for the very very new compositing and blending stuff which is only available behind a flag to the best of my knowledge.)

It is possible to get a multiply effect with SVG filters, but you have to follow SVG filter conventions as well as be aware of the subset of filter capabilities that are implemented in today's browsers. It can be challening to shoe-horn a properly sized filter effect into an existing SVG file that's combined with CSS because of unit system differences & quirks.

This is a version of your graphic done entirely within an SVG inline element that shows that it's possible to get a multiply effect but if it's all done within the SVG universe.

```
 <defs>
    <filter id="multiply">
       <feImage xlink:href="http://imageshack.com/a/img21/7676/y2hg.jpg" result="bg"/> 
       <feBlend mode="multiply" in="SourceGraphic" in2="bg"/>
    </filter>
 </defs>
   <g filter="url(#multiply)"> etc.
```

FWIW: the interactions between CSS and SVG unit systems as well as filter units make this challenging to size correctly.

Comment: Fiddle link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to do this with ['mix-blend-mode'](http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode), when browsers implement the [Compositing and Blending Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1) specification.

```
#logo:hover {
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7GLE/2/).

In Chrome Canary, enable the experimental web platform features flag (chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features), to see it working.

Comment: Very interesting, I hope it get released soon.$

Comment: as of june 2015 this is implemented in chrome, firefox, opera; partially in safari and not in IE. see http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found 2 different ways to do it thanks for Paulie_D.

1) Pixastic : http://www.pixastic.com/lib/

it's a javascript library allowing the use of blend mode. However it isn't compatible with IE however according to the doc IE has a way to it with some native filters.

2) In my case I just wanted to see the lines of my file, thus by using photoshop channels I made a alpha mosaic of the wall.

I dont really know which one is the more optimized option but I went for the second option as it made my background lighter due to the mosaic (arround 40kb vs 200kb before).

Thanks a lot to Paulie, I really do hope that in the future they'll implement a multiply effect in browsers.